# how to store adress memory of an object in array

Tags: c++

I want to Store an address memory of object (Etudiant) in listeEtudiants
i don't know what i have to do
do my code is correct ?

```
class Personne {
public:
    string personne_nom;
    int personne_age;

};
class Etudiant : public Personne {
public:
    string filiere;
    int etudiant_niveau;
};
class Professeur : public Personne {
public:
    string professeur_specialite;
};
class Ecole{
void ajouterEtudiant(Etudiant e) {
            cout << "entrer le nom de l'etudiant:";
            cin >> e.personne_nom;
            cout << "entrer l'age:";
            cin >> e.personne_age;
            cout << "entrer filiere:";
            cin >> e.filiere;
            cout << "entrer niveau:";
            cin >> e.etudiant_niveau;
            listeEtudiants[nbEtudiants] = ???;
            nbEtudiants++;
        }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the address? I think this is an XY problem

Comment: You most likely don't want to do what you ask as it will be a useless address after the function ends. `e` is a local variable to the function it no longer exists after the function ends. Storing it's address is pointless. If you store it and attempt to use it outside of this function you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: If you need an address you most likely will need dynamic allocation. I assume you are not using smart pointers so you will need to use `new` and remember to free the pointer when removing nodes

Comment: You don't need pointers. You can use std::vector<Etudiant> listeEtudiants; listeEtudiants.push_back(e); (and then pass e by reference to avoid a copy of student being made at the function call)

Comment: `listeEtudiants` -- You didn't show what this is.

Comment: I don't think its name matches what it is but my guess is its an array of `Etudiant*` however it would be a much better question if that was confirmed in the question itself. [mcve]

Comment: In C++, raw pointers and arrays should only be used in low level code. This seems to be high level enough to only use standard containers and smart pointers. Here, I think that you only need to add a `std::vector<Etudiant>` to your `Ecole` class.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we have to talk about a few things.

First, I strongly discourage you from using raw pointers. Use smart pointers. I'll show you an example shortly.

Next, this method:

```
 void ajouterEtudiant(Etudiant e);
```

This is going to be problematic for you. What happens is that e comes in as a COPY of whatever is passed to it, and when the method goes away, the value goes away. If you store the address of e, it's a pointer to bad data after that.

I could change that method like this:

```
 std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Etudiant>> listeEtudiants;
 // note that you no longer need a counter as the vector will
 // keep it for you.

 void ajouterEtudiant() {
      shared_ptr<Etudiant> newStudent = std::make_shared<Etudiant>();
      ... all the code to load the newStudent ...
      listeEtudiants.push_back(newStudent);
 }
```

You could then do this:

```
 cout << "Number of students: " << listeEtudiants.size() << endl;

 for (const std::shared_ptr<Etudiant> &ptr: listeEtudiants) {
    cout << "Name: " ptr->name << endl;
    ...

 }
```

Or whatever fields you have. You get the idea.

Learning to use the combination of smart pointers and std::vector is critical to success programming C++.